# Multiple "\a" not working

Tags: c

I have started programming in C a few days ago. I am currently using the book "C programming for absolute beginners". At the end of the printf chapter an example is used to make the computer beep a more than one time, but it only beeps once, here is the code: `printf("\n\a\n\a\n\a\n\aSkip a few lines, and beep a few beeps. \n\n\n");`.

I am running windows 10 64-bit and using Code::Blocks 13.12.

Edit 1 : I want the sound to come through the speakers(headphones/headset) through windows.

Edit 2 : Looks like all the sounds play at once and the last one is the only one that completes, how can I prevent that?

Comment: I don't see _any_ `\b` in your `printf()` statement.

Comment: I suspect it doesn't pause for a beep, so all beeps get played at once.

Comment: @AlexYan We still have cases with a speaker.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My bad, fixed the title

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson How can I pause for a beep? So I can have multiple ones.

Comment: you could try to have multiple printf statements. The line you gave gives multiple beeps in Windows 7 (at least on my machine).

Comment: @JohnColeman on mine too, but I noted that the sound is coming from the audio output, not from the crude circuit board beeper, and, the message is printed to console before the beeps have finished.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have listened to it carefully, The beeps go all at once(with new ones cancelling old ones) what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: AFAIK, on-board speakers were deprecated, and were removed entirely with the 64-bit transition. If your computer still has one then it's probably so 32-bit operating systems can still use it.

Comment: Pause between the beeps, fine tune the pauses to get them to play however you want.

Comment: I'm getting the same audio output as Weather Vane, and I'm using Windows 10 (64-bit). It's only one beep on my system. Strangely enough, if I run the posted `printf` invocation in a long enough loop, the command prompt locks up. Even `i=0..499` was too long for my system!

Comment: @EvanCarslake How can I do the pauses plz

Comment: @immibis what happened to "beep codes"? This older 64-bit Windows 7 uses them, however my newer 64-bit Windows 10 (which I hate) does not beep on power-up.

Comment: @H.Malkawi when I run the executable directly from Windows, I get no beeps at all, but if I force the program to wait by adding `getchar();` after the `printf` statement, I hear them all.

Comment: @WeatherVane You can still trigger a beep. Booting a Debian LiveCD for example will beep on startup (at least on my machine that was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10). However, Windows now, much like the Konsole terminal emulator in KDE (last I checked), seems to redirect the beep codes and produces normal audio output rather than old-school PC speaker beeps.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune my comment about "beep codes" was about the diagnostics POST beep codes issued by the BIOS (now UEFI), before the OS has booted.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know anything about UEFI other than the fact that it has supplanted the BIOS as we knew it. Sorry for misunderstanding. Off-topic, [they might not be standardized yet?](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/331834-30-list-beep-codes-uefi)

Comment: @H.Malkawi **My advice: don't worry about it since one is usually enough to get a user's attention.** I'm honestly not sure how printing a sequence of `\a` is a teaching/learning exercise since it would always play the same note anyway... You wouldn't ordinarily use multiple beeps since such beeps in one tone would just be annoying (long and loud and wouldn't stop until all of them were finished, even after you've killed the program). While I miss hearing it for nostalgic reasons, I'm definitely glad the behavior was changed!

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I agree with you a 100%, what is programming if you can't play with your code and have fun right? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beeps are being issued too fast, so subsequent beeps are cancelling earlier ones, and you will hear only one sound.

You can use the Windows API [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) function to pause for a given number of milliseconds:

```
#include <windows.h>

...

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

  // Issue a newline and a beep.
  printf("\n\a");

  // Pause for half a second.
  Sleep(500);

}
```

On POSIX systems, you can use the [`nanosleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) function, whose resolution is in microseconds:

```
#include <time.h>

...

struct timespec delay;
delay.tv_sec = 0;
delay.tv_usec = 500000;
nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
```

Comment: This is actually the first time I hear about <windows.h>. I should do more research to figure out more commands, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @H.Malkawi: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx) is a great resource for learning about the Windows API.